# How to make a Plotly scatter plot without marker dots?

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to create a series of hatched square PNGs - similarly to the swatches shown [here](https://riccardoscalco.it/textures/) towards the end of the page.

These are not for use on the web - so I think using textures.js would be too much of a roundabout route, and I stumbled upon Plotly, and specifically [this](https://plotly.com/python/pattern-hatching-texture/)

I got as far as this

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

xy = [
    [0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1], [0, 0]
]


fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(x=[ co[0] for co in xy ], y=[ co[1] for co in xy ],
                           fill="toself", marker={'size': 0 }
))

fig.update_layout(showlegend=False)
fig.update_xaxes(visible=False)
fig.update_yaxes(visible=False)

img_bytes = fig.to_image(format="png")


fig.write_image("foo.png")
```

which generates this:
[image]

but I am struggling to NOT show the dots at the corners of the rectangle.

How do I do that? I know that a scatterplot without points is kind of nonsensical, so if there is a cleaner solution that's fine too.

(I suppose I will figure out how to NOT have lines and background and how to fill it with the hatch - but help is welcome on that too)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To plot without lines and without markers

```py
fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(x=[ co[0] for co in xy ], y=[ co[1] for co in xy ],
                           fill="toself", mode='text'
))
```

To plot without markers but with lines

```py
fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(x=[ co[0] for co in xy ], y=[ co[1] for co in xy ],
                           fill="toself", mode='lines'
))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following line:

```
mode ="lines",
```

see the total code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

xy = [    [0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1], [0, 0]]

fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(x=[ co[0] for co in xy ], y=[ co[1] for co in xy ],
                           fill="toself",
                           mode ="lines",
                        #    marker={'size': 0 }
))

fig.update_layout(showlegend=False)
fig.update_xaxes(visible=False)
fig.update_yaxes(visible=False)

img_bytes = fig.to_image(format="png")
fig.write_image("foo.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with marker opacity:

```
fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(x=[ co[0] for co in xy ], y=[ co[1] for co in xy ],
                           fill="toself", marker={'opacity': 0}
))
```